# Foreach list with different database status

Tags: php, database, foreach

I am working on a project (real estate) and need to display a list of properties. (pictures)
The properties are in a database. Properties can have two 'objects_status': 1=for sale, 2=sold.
Sold properties display a 'sold' banner on top of the image.

I did manage to display the properties, using 'foreach'. It displays properties randomly. 
What I want to add is the following: There has always to be 2 sold properties on the list.

I don't want to use 2 seperate foreach (first one to show 2 sold en second one to show for sale properties), but show the 2 sold properties randomly between the for sale properties.

The code I use:

```
  <?php foreach($aBuildings as $aBuilding): ?>
                <div class="span2 <?php echo ($aBuilding['objects_status'] == 1 ? 'sold' : ''); ?>">
                    <figure>
                        <?php if($aBuilding['objects_status'] == 1){ echo '<div class="sold-banner">Afgelopen</div>';} else if($aBuilding['objects_status'] == 2){ echo '<div class="verkocht-banner">Verkocht</div>';} else{ echo '<div class="days-left">' . $aBuilding['daysleft'] . '</div>';} ?>
                        <img src="/uploads/woningen/thumb/<?=$aBuilding['objects_photo_thumb']?>" alt="">
                    </figure>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Normaal &euro; <?php echo number_format($aBuilding['objects_price'], 0, '', '.'); ?></li>
                        <li class="now">Nu &euro; <?php echo number_format($aBuilding['objects_discount_price'], 0, '', '.'); ?></li>
                        <li>Korting <?php echo round(-1 * ($aBuilding['objects_discount_price'] / $aBuilding['objects_price'] * 100 - 100)); ?>%</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I can't seem to get it work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing DB query to pull back the results you want. For example if you are writing in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM properties AS sale
WHERE sale.objects_status = "for sale"
   UNION
SELECT *
FROM properties AS sold
WHERE sold.objects_status = "sold"
LIMIT 2
```

I'm guessing your DB schema obviously. Then you can foreach over the results like your original code.

Comment: you can use shuffle() to randomise the list returned by the query. http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php